# Making a query through relation property in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have this One to Many relation between Artist and Album, an artist can be related to many albums, but an album can only be associated to one Artist.

My Artist model:

```
<?php


class Artist extends Eloquent {

  public function albums()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('Album');
  }

}
```

My Album model:

```
<?php


class Album extends Eloquent {

  public function artist()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('Artist');
  }

}
```

I learned how to get all the albums of an artist, as well as retrieving the artist of an album. But I still don't know how to do this query:

> Get all the albums whom artist is "Linkin Park"

What I'm currently doing is this:

```
$artist = Artist::where('name','=','Linkin Park')->first();

$albums = Album::where('artist_id','=',$artist->id)->get();
```

I get what I need but I was wondering if there is other way to do this. Something like (I know is wrong):

```
$albums = Album::where('artist','=','Linkin Park');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a way to do it by looking at the [examples in the official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations).

The query would be like this:

```
$albums = Album::whereHas('artist', function($q)
{
    $q->where('name', '=', 'Linkin Park');

})->get();
```